# I'm building a flask website but I get the error: sqlalchemy.exc.NoForeignKeysError

Tags: python, sql, database, flask, foreign-keys

I'm trying to build a very simple website where users can take notes. I want to have a database that lets users sign up and login to my website. When I run main.py and go to the link of the website and try to sign up I get this error:

sqlalchemy.exc.NoForeignKeysError: Could not determine join condition between parent/child tables on relationship User.notes - there are no foreign keys linking these tables. Ensure that referencing columns are associated with a ForeignKey or ForeignKeyConstraint, or specify a 'primaryjoin' expression.

This is are the relevant codes:

auth.py

```
def sign_up():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        email = request.form.get('email')
        first_name = request.form.get('firstName')
        password1 = request.form.get('password1')
        password2 = request.form.get('password2')

        if len(email) < 4:
            flash('Email must be greater than 3 characters.', category='error')
        elif len(first_name) < 2:
            flash('First name must be greater than 1 character.', category='error')
        elif password1 != password2:
            flash('Passwords don\'t match.', category='error')
        elif len(password1) < 7:
            flash('Password must be at least 7 characters.', category='error')
        else:
            new_user = User(email=email, first_name=first_name, password=generate_password_hash(password1, method='sha256'))
            db.session.add(new_user)
            db.session.commit()
            flash('Account created!',category='success')
            return redirect(url_for('views.home'))

    return render_template('sign_up.html')
```

models.py

```
class Note(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    data = db.Column(db.String(10000))
    date = db.Column(db.DateTime(timezone=True), default=func.now())
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user_id'))

class User(db.Model,UserMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(150), unique=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(150))
    first_name = db.Column(db.String(150))
    notes = db.relationship('Note')
```

I would really appreciate some help with this.

Answer (score 0):

Change the

```
user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user_id'))
```

to

```
user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
```

U have the symbol "_" between user and id, while you should have dot "."

Comment: I did that but it now displays the error: sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such table: user
[SQL: INSERT INTO user (email, password, first_name) VALUES (?, ?, ?)]

Comment: It works in my similar project:  `class Note(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    data = db.Column(db.String(10000))
    date = db.Column(db.DateTime(timezone=True), default=func.now())
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))

class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(20), unique=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(50), unique=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(150))
    notes = db.relationship('Note')` U have to delete already created .db